# Power automate - Custom connector - Webhook trigger with dynamic schema properties

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I'm trying to create a webhook trigger in Power Automate via the OpenApi spec.
The webhook url must be in the body and it's required, but I also want to have dynamic properties in the body aswell. So far I have this:

```
"/webhook/triggers/{entityType}": {
      "x-ms-notification-content": {
        "description": "When a operation is performed on a entity",
        "x-ms-summary": "When a operation is performed on a entity",
        "schema": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "data": {
              "type": "object",
              "x-ms-dynamic-schema": {
                "operationId": "GetDynamicSchema",
                "parameters": {
                  "entityType": {
                    "parameter": "entityType"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "source": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "time": {
              "format": "date-time",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "dataSchema": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "dataContentType": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "extensionAttributes": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "description": "When a operation is performed on a entity",
        "x-ms-trigger": "single",
        "x-ms-visibility": "important",
        "summary": "When a operation is performed on a entity",
        "operationId": "RegisterTriggerWithEntity",
        "consumes": ["application/json"],
        "produces": ["application/json"],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "entityType",
            "x-ms-summary": "Entity",
            "description": "The entity",
            "x-ms-url-encoding": "single",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "x-ms-dynamic-values": {
              "operationId": "GetEntityTypes",
              "value-path": "name",
              "value-title": "description"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "body",
            "in": "body",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "webhookUrl": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "x-ms-notification-url": true,
                  "x-ms-visibility": "internal"
                },
                "data": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "x-ms-dynamic-schema": {
                    "operationId": "GetSchema",
                    "parameters": {
                      "entityType": {
                        "parameter": "entityType"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "x-ms-dynamic-properties": {
                    "operationId": "GetSchema",
                    "parameters": {
                      "entityType": {
                        "parameterReference": "entityType"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "webhookUrl"
              ],
              "x-ms-visibility": "important"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            "description": "Created"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Which passes validation, I also have the schema properties prompted in the UI ready to be provided by the user, but on saving the flow, I get the following `OpenApiOperationParameterValidationFailed`:

```
Flow save failed with code 'OpenApiOperationParameterValidationFailed' and message 'Input parameter 'body' validation failed in workflow operation 'When_a_operation_is_performed_on_a_entity': The API operation 'RegisterTriggerWithEntity' requires the property 'body/data' to be set to one of its defined enum values '[]' but is set to '{ "firstProperty": "testValue" }'.'.
```

What might be the problem with this flow? What is the suggested way of having a webhook trigger with dynamic schema properties?

Comment: Have you gone through [Webhook as a trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-webhook-trigger) and [Dynamic Schema Properties](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/Custom-API-WebHook-Trigger-dynamic-WebHook-response-schema/m-p/26062#M12)

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT, yes, the second link is for the dynamic schema in the response schema, not in the request body.

Comment: here is a similar issue that you can refer to https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/OpenApiOperationParameterValidationFailed/m-p/783525#M19853